# How to handle error returning from a graphql backend on react admin?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin

I want to show errors received from my back-end on submitting a simpleForm for creating a new product.

my code for querybuilder:

```
       case 'CREATE':
                if (typeof resource !== 'undefined' && resource.type.name === 'Product'){
                    result = {
                        query: PRODUCT_CREATE_ONE,
                        variables: { input: params.data },
                        parseResponse: response => ({
                            data: response.data.productCreate.product,
                            errors: response.data.productCreate.errors,
                        }),
                    }
 
 
                };
```

I can add the product successfully on the first attempt! but when i try to add it with an existing unique key i get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null
    at validateResponseFormat (validateResponseFormat.js:25)
    at performPessimisticQuery.js:42
```

what i'm receiving from server:

```
{
  "data": {
    "productCreate": {
      "product": null,
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "Product with this Slug already exists.",
          "__typename": "ProductError"
        }
      ],
      "__typename": "ProductCreate"
    }
  }
}
```

what i'm expecting,is when the errors[] not empty is to show a notification  with the errors message

Is there any way to handle errors received from the back-end and how ?

Comment: You are using apollo client?

Comment: Yes, i'm using apollo client 
` const client = new ApolloClient({
            link: httpLink,
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
            defaultOptions,
        });`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the `ErrorLink` from apollo.

```
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";

// Log any GraphQL errors or network error that occurred
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    );
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Source: [Apollo Error Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error/)

This will be triggered when an error inside a request occures and you are able handle it by e.g. an ErrorBoundary.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dani but it's not working for me. i get the same issue! and this code not loading when i submit my form

Comment: Sorry i don't get it

Comment: Graphql server not returning a graphqlErrors or nertworkError because i don't want this behavior!  graphql return a 200 response when he found a key already exist with errors

Comment: So, that is the expected behaviour of a gql query. It returns 200 because the http request was successfull, but the query wasn't. You have to handle the errors in the error link or in your component.